# How to change xml element value in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
<Code>D:picture\simple</Code>
<Password>picture</Password>
</Settings>
```

I want to change the value which is inside Code and Password.How can I change the value.

Comment: There are libraries that allow you to read XML files and modify them, here's a tutorial that will teach you how to do it: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/introduction/

Answer (score 2):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("path/to/xml/somewhere");

root.Element("Code").Value= "newcode";
root.Element("Password").Value ="Penis *gnhihihi*";
//only in Linqpad
root.Dump();
```

And there you have it. This is one way to change it.
It is up to you how you save it back to an xml file